# Dropdown is not working on Safari browser of iPad 2

Tags: javascript

HTML:

```
<select class="form-control selectpicker" name="username" id="username" data-size="5">
</select>
```

JS:

```
var usernames = ["Bren", "Jobs"];

var $username = $("#username");
$.each(usernames, function(key, value){
   $username.append("<option value=\""+value+"\">"+value+"</option>");
});
$username.selectpicker("refresh");
```

On PC:

[image]

On Safari iPad 2:

[image]

Comment: Do you get JavaScript errors?

Comment: It's not any error.

Answer (score -1):

This is working example. You should check if you have included all the required dependencies.

```js
var usernames = ["Bren", "Jobs"];

var $username = $("#username");
$.each(usernames, function(key, value){
   $username.append("<option value=\""+value+"\">"+value+"</option>");
});
$username.selectpicker("refresh");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.4/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.12.4/css/bootstrap-select.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<select class="form-control selectpicker" name="username" id="username" data-size="5">
</select>
```